# WordPress 3 botches my Custom Meta Box values on Save

Tags: theme-development

My theme has code that places a custom meta box on the Page editor interface for toggling noindex and/or nofollow attributes to the page.

Its a simple little deal with two checkboxes, one says noindex, the other says nofollow.

These work flawlessly in all versions of WP prior to 3.0.1

I've found that in 3.0.1, the values of the checkboxes are not saved. No matter what I do, they always come up unchecked, and the values are not being passed to the database either (its not just reporting unchecked in the interface, it never sends the values to the db)

I'm at a loss at what's different and how to get my code to work with 3.0.1

Does anyone know of what might have changed to make these checkbox values not pass when the page is Updated in WP 3.0.1?

```
// ===================
// = POST OPTION BOX =
// ===================

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_options_box');

function my_post_options_box() {
    if ( function_exists('add_meta_box') ) { 
        add_meta_box('categorydiv', __('Page Index Options'), 'post_categories_meta_box_modified', 'page', 'side', 'high');
    }
}

//adds the custom categories box
function post_categories_meta_box_modified($post) {
global $post, $noindexCat, $nofollowCat;
    $noindexCat = get_cat_ID('noindex');
    $nofollowCat = get_cat_ID('nofollow');
    if(in_category("noindex")){ $noindexChecked = " checked='checked'";} 
    if(in_category("nofollow")){ $nofollowChecked = " checked='checked'";}
?>
<div id="categories-all" class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <ul id="categorychecklist" class="list:category categorychecklist form-no-clear">
        <li id='category-<?php echo $noindexCat ?>' class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="<?php echo $noindexCat ?>" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-<?php echo $noindexCat ?>"<?php echo $noindexChecked ?> /> noindex</label></li> 
        <li id='category-<?php echo $nofollowCat ?>' class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="<?php echo $nofollowCat ?>" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-<?php echo $nofollowCat ?>"<?php echo $nofollowChecked ?> /> nofollow</label></li> 
        <li id='category-1' class="popular-category" style="display:none;"><label class="selectit"><input value="1" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-1" checked="checked"/> Uncategorized</label></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this isn't using custom post meta ... you're trying to retrieve categories and use the presence of those categories to check the boxes.  I also don't see any script to save the values once you've clicked them ...  When this *did* work, I assume it was a very hackish solution, so I'm not surprised that it's unstable and has broken.

However, you *can* actually use custom post meta to do what it is you want to do.  Use the following script instead:

```
// ===================
// = POST OPTION BOX =
// ===================

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_options_box');

function my_post_options_box() {
    if ( function_exists('add_meta_box') ) { 
        add_meta_box('categorydiv', __('Page Index Options'), 'post_categories_meta_box_modified', 'page', 'side', 'high');
    }
}

//adds the custom categories box
function post_categories_meta_box_modified() {
    global $post;
    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_noIndex', true) ) $noindexChecked = " checked='checked'";
    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_noFollow', true) ) $nofollowChecked = " checked='checked'";
?>
<div id="categories-all" class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <ul id="categorychecklist" class="list:category categorychecklist form-no-clear">
        <li id='noIndex' class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="noIndex" type="checkbox" name="chk_noIndex" id="chk_noIndex"<?php echo $noindexChecked ?> /> noindex</label></li> 
        <li id='noFollow' class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="noFollow" type="checkbox" name="chk_noFollow" id="chk_noFollow"<?php echo $nofollowChecked ?> /> nofollow</label></li>  
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
}

function save_post_categories_meta($post_id) {
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;

    $noIndex = $_POST['chk_noIndex'];
    $noFollow = $_POST['chk_noFollow'];

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_noIndex', $noIndex );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_noFollow', $noFollow );

    return $post_id;
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_post_categories_meta');
```

This will store Boolean flags in the custom post meta fields "noIndex" and "noFollow", retrieve the values of those fields to use in your custom meta box, and allow you to easily access them elsewhere in your site.  Just use `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-name', true )` to retrieve them.

Comment: Anytime someone prefaces their comment with "First of all...", my shields engage... But thanks for your full response and I'll check it out.

Comment: @EAMann - This is definitely a more elegant solution, but one small problem....The checkboxes are coming up checked regardless of the previous state on publish (even on newly created pages). Any ideas what's causing that? I'm testing it on 2.9.1 presently.

Comment: Not sure, but I'll double check the logic later today and get right back to you.  Also, sorry for the "First of all..." start ... :-)

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate the quick help :) Been using categories as a hack and if I can get this to work, I'll move all my custom post settings to this method.

Comment: @EAMann - I did notice a type on chk_noIndex and ck_noIndex, but correcting it had no effect.

Comment: *@Scott B* Thanks for pointing out the typo ... I fixed it, and like I said I'll double-check the solution this afternoon and let you know what to change to get it working ...

Comment: *@Scott B* OK, I had a few spare minutes and figured it out :-)  I forgot to set the third parameter of `get_post_meta` to `true` (it defaults to `false`) ... if set to `true` it returns a single value, if set to `false` it returns an array.  We needed it to return a single value to work properly.  Just ran this through a quick test on my demo site and it seems to work just fine (on WP 3.0.1 that is...).

Comment: I've also edited my solution to hide the custom fields from the default Custom Fields section as per [your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/how-can-i-remove-specific-custom-post-meta-from-the-custom-fields-fieldset).

Comment: consider using a bitmask: 0: none; 1: nofollow; 2: noindex (; 3: both). Then you only need one post meta field to save. And you can check with $value & 1 and $value & 2 for each of them.

Comment: @EAmann: you are the "Mann"! Works flawlessly in 2.9.1 and 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to also suggest the use of [WPAlchemy Meta Box](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) (a php class i've created) for creating your meta boxes ...

Comment: -1 For pitching your own plugin without disclosing that it's your plugin.