# How can I remove specific custom post meta from the "Custom Fields" fieldset?

Tags: theme-development

I've created a custom meta box to handle certain custom post meta fields and I don't want the clutter of having these custom fields duplicated down in the "Custom Fields" area.

How can I remove specific custom post meta from the "Custom Fields" fieldset?

Comment: Can anyone provide a suggestion on how to use the is_protected_meta hook to hide multiple custom field keys based on a substring that’s in the key name? There’a plugin that I’m using that added a whole bunch of custom field keys and I want to hide them from the admin interface without breaking the plugin. For example, I want to hide ALL custom field keys that start with “review-” or “bsf-”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide a custom field from the "Custom Fields" section, prefix it with an underscore.  So `add_post_meta($id, 'name', 'value');` becomes `add_post_meta($id, '_name', 'value');`.

Here's a good reference for backup:

- [How to Hide Your Plugin's Custom Fields](http://www.johnkolbert.com/wordpress/how-to-hide-your-plugins-custom-fields/)

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the is_protected_meta filter and return true for any custom field you want to hide.

```
add_filter('is_protected_meta', 'my_is_protected_meta_filter', 10, 2);
function my_is_protected_meta_filter($protected, $meta_key) {
    return $meta_key == 'meta-name' ? true : $protected;
}
```

Comment: Clean up your code please. Use the `{}` sign above the editor to add code in a code block. Thank you